# How to set Real IP in Webhook in Telegram Bot

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I have faced a problem in telegram bot for some days. I have developed a system in telegram bot in php where someone text in `Telegram Group` and auto reply comes from Group as he/she expect. It works fine for a website like below

```
https://api.telegram.org/botmy_token/setwebhook?url=https://example.com/bot/index.php
```

Where **my_token** is Bot Father Token

But When I use like this below

```
https://api.telegram.org/botmy_token/setwebhook?url=https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/DevOps2019/onmv4_1/index.php?e=pabx&p=all_list&f=all&l=sp_bot.php
```

Or

```
https://api.telegram.org/botmy_token/setwebhook?url=https://example.net/DevOps2019/onmv4_1/index.php?e=pabx&p=all_list&f=all&l=sp_bot.php
```

It shows me an error

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: bad webhook: IP address xxx.xxx.xx.xx is reserved"}
```

**Note:**

```
https://example.net/DevOps2019/onmv4_1/index.php?e=pabx&p=all_list&f=all&l=sp_bot.php
```

Above link is private network. It is not allowed to public access. My problem is how to set above link as webhook in telegram bot.

Comment: "It is not allowed to public access"; so telegram can't reach it, therefore you can't use it as a webhook url? Telegram needs to be able to resolve the address and send a request to the script.

Comment: @0stone0, Thanks for your comment. Have any alternative solution to resolve the problem?

Comment: What do you expect as an answer? Thats how web-hooks work, server1 (telegram) needs to be able to send requests to server2 (your machine). If that route isn't public available, there's no way... You should use a domain/ip thats public available.

Answer (score 2):

> Above link is private network.

Telegram servers can't access your private network. Host your bot on public hosting or server.